# JQuery Hover Image Swap Problem

Tags: jquery

I have been attempting to implement the JQuery Hover Implementation for a page that now uses JavaScript.

mousing over the Thumb Image should change the Lower Image accordingly, and when you mouse out the background-color should return to the background color #FFFFFF.

I think that Im still missing something in the JavaScript and if someone sees the problem, I would really greatly appreciate it.

Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/P8baa/

Here is the link to the site which illustrates the behavior: http://www.odontex.net/Ingles/mexico/aboutus-mexicoci.html

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your divs have `id="content"` changing them to `class="content` would be a start

Answer (score 3):

I would use something like this...

Mark all the thumbs with e.g. class "thumb" and give them an attribute something like references="X", where X is the number of the thumb. Then, make content boxes with class="content" thumbref="X" with the same meaning...then

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".content").hide();
    $(".thumb").hover(
        function(){
            $(".content[thumbref="+$(this).attr("references")+"]").show()
        },
        function(){
            $(".content[thumbref="+$(this).attr("references")+"]").hide()
        }
    );
});
```

and I think it should do the trick:)

Comment: @Lord when you say to give the "Thumbs" an attribute of 1 2 or 3, could you demonstrate that?  Im confused

Comment: make <div class='thumb' references='3'>...image of the thumb...</div>

Comment: @Lord I think Im still missing something because its not working in my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/P8baa/

Comment: `id="content"` on each of the image divs should be `class="content"`

Comment: @kingjiv he kind of bailed, but I guess a vote is better?  since I cant give 2 checkmarks.

Comment: well...the important thing about all this is if you made it work:)) Marks etc. are just  fun:)) Go on fighting;-)